# to get specific item from list obltained through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code,

```
var applications = from a in applications1.Entities.ToList()
                           select new
                           {
                               name = a.Attributes["sia_name"].ToString(),
                               applicationId = a.Attributes["sia_applicationid"].ToString(),

                               isDraftMode = a.Attributes.Contains("sia_applicationmode") ? a.FormattedValues["sia_applicationmode"].ToString().ToLower() == "draft" ? true : false : false
                           };
```

in this code I have applications which contains name ,applicationid,and isdraftmode,
now I want to fetch applicationid from var application so that I can pass it to session

how can it be achive

```
 Session["ApplicationID"]=applications
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like

```
Session["ApplicationID"]=applications.Select(m => m.applicationId).First();
```

it would give you first applicationId. If you want to select applicationId based on condition then you can do it like

```
Session["ApplicationID"]=applications.Select(m => m.applicationId).First(x => x.property == condition);
```

and for all the applicationid do it like

```
Session["ApplicationID"]=applications.Select(m => m.applicationId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a query which selects multiple properties in an anonymous type and you need to select one specific property from it to write it into session?

```
Session["ApplicationID"] = applications
    .Select(x => x.applicationId)
    .ToList();  // i would "materialize" it in a collection to avoid side effect due to lazy evaluation
```

or do you instead want to get a specific item from it, for example via `sia_name`?

```
var sia = applications.FirstOrDefault(x => x.sia_name == "InsertName");
if(sia != null)
    Session["ApplicationID"] =  sia.applicationId;
```